# Can I have a column in my table that is hash value of another column and is automatically computed?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Kanji] (
    [KanjiId]              UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Text]                 NVARCHAR (5)     NOT NULL,
    [Freq]                 INT              NULL,
    [Grade]                INT              NULL,
}
```

There are a large number of rows in this table and I would like to be able to select just 10%.  Ideally I would like to have a column (maybe a computed column) in the table that was something like a hash value for the contents of the [Text] column. A hash that was a number from 0-9 so I could then select all rows that had this value.

Is there some way that I can create a column like this?

Comment: What sort of hashing function do you have in mind?  If you were to use the sort that Java or C# uses for a hash map, then you might never got two rows with the same hash.  Or at least you would need a very large table before collisions started to happen.

Comment: I mean there are ways you could do this, for example, you could just do something like `[partCol] AS CHECKSUM([Text]) % 10 PERSISTED` which theoretically should roughly split your table into 10. But really, why are you selecting 10% at a time? There seems to be some other issue you might want to solve in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Kanji] (
    [KanjiId]              UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Text]                 NVARCHAR (5)     NOT NULL,
    [Freq]                 INT              NULL,
    [Grade]                INT              NULL,
    [Hash]  AS (CONVERT([bigint],hashbytes('md5',[Name]))%(5)+(5)),
}
```

You'll get values from -9 to 9, for example.

Comment: Is there a way that I could modify this to give values between 0 and 9? thanks